# Reordering Fields on Extended Content Type

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have extended a basic Plone content type using archetypes.schemaextender. I need to reorder the fields on the edit page. When I do, the reordered fields appear in a new tab called "content" on the edit interface. How can I get the fields to appear in the "default" tab of the edit interface instead?

Here is the code snippet from my extender.py:

```
class extenddocument(object):
    adapts(IATDocument)
    implements(IOrderableSchemaExtender, IBrowserLayerAwareExtender)

    layer = IextenddocumentLayer

    fields = [
        _ExtensionStringField(
            name='longTitle',
            widget=StringWidget(
                label=u'Long Title',
                description=u'Optional descriptive title to replace default title as the page heading',
                size='50',
            ),
            required=False,
            searchable=True,
        ),
    ]

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def getOrder(self, schematas):
            """ Manipulate the order in which fields appear.
                @param schematas: Dictonary of schemata name -> field lists
                @return: Dictionary of reordered field lists per schemata.
            """
            schematas["Content"] = ['title', 'longTitle', 'description', 'text']
            return schematas

    def getFields(self):
        return self.fields
```

attached is the edit tab view:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the getOrder method, assign your list of fields to schematas['default'] instead of to schematas['Content'].

Comment: When I changed to schematas['default'] I get this error:

Exception Type ValueError
Exception Value The number of fields in the new order differs from the number of fields in the schema.

...
Module archetypes.schemaextender.extender, line 144, in cachingInstanceSchemaFactory
Module archetypes.schemaextender.extender, line 198, in instanceSchemaFactory
Module archetypes.schemaextender.extender, line 66, in validate_schema_order

Answer (score 1):

Or, as you actually don't need an extra-fieldset, because and added field will be appended to the default-fieldset anyway, you could also just reorder your field – instead of the whole fieldset – as described here:

http://developer.plone.org/content/archetypes/fields.html#reordering-fields

Here is a nice documentation of Inqbus, which gives you an overview of the possibilities of reordering fields and fielsets, it's in German, but the code-parts are self-explaining:

http://inqbus-hosting.de/support/dokumentation/docs/plone-archetypes-schemata-und-fields